# Programs for visualizing math designed for laymen?

Tags: visualization

I'm looking for interactive applications that are for university topics (designed for windows) in mathematics only , preferably something that doesn't include programming languages to use because those confuse me.

I'm looking for Something where you can just input the data akin to 3D - Xplor math. Another good example would be Geomview where you view and manipulate three-dimensional objects: you use the mouse to rotate, translate, zoom in and out, and so on. However this is designed for Unix.

I've looked at programs like Matlab, mathematica , octave , maplesoft but those seem technical and suited for professionals with experience.

The topics I am referring to include: algebra and trigonometry , linear algebra , calculus , differential geometry , numerical methods, sampling theory and signal processing , matrix equations , optimization and computational geometry.

If you can't provide any suggestions , places to start to learn the more technical programs are welcomed.

Comment: GeoGebra??! $\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\$

Comment: This sounds like you're shying away from "professional software", because you perceive them as "professional". They can be used at many levels of experience. Programmers often find that programming language does things more simply than some graphical user interface. Because one can clearly see, what's being done and it can be encapsulated to be readable. And distributed as a simple text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would highly recommend learning one of MATLAB, Mathematica, MathCAD or whatever. Among them, I recommend MATLAB. There is practically nothing that cannot be done in MATLAB. (No flame wars please).

I stand by [MATLAB Demystified](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071485511). Its a wonderful book and starts with no assumptions.

If you don't have access to MATLAB, give a shot to [Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/download.html). It is very similar and more often than not, the codes of MATLAB will work with no or little modifications.

Answer (score 2):

If Mathematica's a bit overwhelming, you can use [Wolfram's website](http://www.wolframalpha.com).  For example, you could query for "plot bessel function" and get [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+bessel+function).

If you're using a Mac, the Grapher app might be what you're looking for.  There's no programming involved and it comes pre-installed.  It's about as easy as plotting gets, it takes both data and math-style expressions, and the visuals are gorgeous.

For Windows, [Microsoft Mathematics 4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/education/en-us/teachers/guides/Pages/Mathematics-guide.aspx) looks promising, but I haven't used it.

IMHO, it's worthwhile to invest time in learning programming if you're doing nearly any kind of university mathematics.